# Apple Outlook Account Remote Wipe

Tags: iphone, email, ms-office

So I recently added an Outlook account to my iPhone for my college. I didn’t notice at the time, but I had to grant it access to remotely wipe my device. I’m not okay with this, and I can use a 3rd party app to see my email. Now, the tech services say they won’t use this ability, but I’m not okay with that level of control.

If I remove the account from my device, will I remove their ability to wipe my phone?

Comment: Can you install the Outlook app? Sometimes that is less draconian and doesn’t need a profile. If work needs a profile installed, I typically make work provide the hardware to our employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allowed a profile to be set on your device, you will need to also remove that profile.

Settings -> General -> Profiles

If you set up Outlook, then you can remove the account from Outlook, that should remove their ability to manage your device.

Comment: Thanks! A few follow-up questions, if you know: If my phone is wiped remotely, is data backed up to my iCloud safe? And, if it were wiped, is the phone “bricked”, or is it just blank like a new device would be?

Comment: The policy allows an MDM to erase the phone.  Despite the fun people have throwing around the word "bricked" for no reason, no, the policy does not allow them to render the phone unusable.

Comment: No, wiping the phone isn't going to brick it.  If you are signed in with your AppleID then the phone is assigned to you though Activation Lock.  It's useless for anyone else but for the AppleID account holder.

The big deal about wiping the phone is more if you somehow lost and can't recover the device.  Then the content is erased as to prevent that secret content from leaking out.  

Most likely your college isn't going to do anything of the sort with your device.  It's just a setting that comes with the Mobile Device Management (MDM) that the college is using.